# MySQL slow query when combining two very fast queries

Tags: mysql, sql, performance

I have two MySQL queries that run very fast, but when I combine them the new query is very slow.

Fast (<1 second, 15 results):

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
Id, Name, Company_Id
FROM people
where Company_Id in (5295, 1834)
and match(Locations) against('austin')
```

Fast (<1 second, 2970 results):

```
select distinct Company_Id from technologies
    where match(Name) against('elastic')
      and Company_Id is not null
```

When I combine the two like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Id, Name, Company_Id
FROM people
where Company_Id in
    ( select Company_Id from technologies
        where match(Name) against('elastic')
          and Company_Id is not null
    )
  and match(Locations) against('austin')
```

The result query takes over 2 minutes to complete. It has 278 rows hit.

I've tried rewriting the slow query a few ways. One other example is like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
`Extent1`.`Id`, `Extent1`.`Name`, `Extent1`.`Company_Id`
FROM `people` AS `Extent1` 
INNER JOIN `technologies` AS `Extent2`
     ON (`Extent1`.`Company_Id` = `Extent2`.`Company_Id`)
WHERE (`Extent1`.`Company_Id` IS NOT NULL) 
 AND ((match(`Extent1`.`Locations`) against('austin')) 
 AND  (match(`Extent2`.`Name`) against('elastic')))
```

I'm using MySQL 5.7 on Windows. I have full text index on the Name and Location columns. My InnoDB Buffer Usage never goes above 40%. I tried to use MySQL workbench to look at the execution plan, but it shows "Explain data not available for statement"

Please let me know if you see anything I could improve or try. Thank you.

Comment: I think the last sentence of Gordon's answer is the bit worth considering.

Comment: Yes, but Locations is not a list. It's a simple longtext (Entity Framework sourced) column with a Full Text index on it. I have the same issue with other Person columns (Name, etc...) that are similar longtext with FT index.

Comment: I would be interested in seeing the output of `EXPLAIN` on this query to see what tables are being scanned and where the search cost is most expensive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`IN ( SELECT ... )` is poorly optimized, at least in older versions of MySQL.  What version are you using?

When using a `FULLTEXT` index (`MATCH...`), that part is performed first, if possible.  This is because nearly always the FT lookup is faster than whatever else is going on.

But when using two fulltext queries, it picks one, then can't use fulltext on the other.

Here's one possible workaround:

- Have a extra table for searches.  It includes both `Name` and `Locations` in it.
- Have `FULLTEXT(Name, Locations)`
- `MATCH (Name, Locations) AGAINST ('+austin +elastic' IN BOOLEAN MODE)`

If necessary, `AND` that with something to verify that it is not, for example, finding a person named 'Austin'.

Another possibility:

5.7 (or 5.6?) *might* be able to optimize this by creating indexes on the subqueries:

```
SELECT ...
    FROM ( SELECT Company_Id FROM ... MATCH(Name) ... ) AS x
    JOIN ( SELECT Company_Id FROM ... MATCH(Locations) ... ) AS y
        USING(Company_id);
```

Provide the `EXPLAIN`; I am hoping to see `<auto-key>`.

Test that.  If it is 'fast', then you may need to add on another `JOIN` and/or `WHERE`.  (I am unclear what your ultimate query needs to be.)

Comment: select * from 
(select Company_Id from people where match(Locations) against ('austin')) as x
join (select Company_Id from technologies where match(Name) against('elastic')) as y
USING(Company_id);

Comment: This worked great. It must have been the "two fulltext queries" thing. I did explain and it shows it's using an <autokey> derived table. Amazingly, the old 'slow' query runs fast now too. Explain says the old 'slow' query is using the <autokey> table now too. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Write the query with the subquery in the `from` clause:

```
select distinct p.Id, p.Name, p.Company_Id
from people p join
     (select Company_Id
      from technologies
      where match(Name) against('elastic') and Company_Id is not null
     ) t
     on p.Company_Id = t.Company_Id
where match(p.Locations) against ('austin');
```

I suspect that you have a problem with your data structure, though.  You should have a `CompanyLocations` table, rather than storing locations in a list in the table.

Comment: Good suggestion, and that query gives me the right results - but, it still took 110 seconds to run for me.